# How do I fix using the three finger tap for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dictionary

I used to be able to highlight a word and then tap with three fingers on the trackpad and a dictionary definition would pop up. Sometime in the last month I haven't been able to do that. Firefox has upgraded maybe once or twice and I upgraded to Mac OSX El Captain.

And yes, I did enable it in Preferences:
[image]
And it does work in other programs since I enabled it.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212527) in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't right now.  Unfortunately, this appears to be a bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212527

Comment: Don't know why but two people down voted your answer.

Comment: They downvoted it because without the link this answer is baseless. And with the link you have to read some other site. Quote the chunk of that thread into this answer that points out what is going/why it's a bug